# Error while using subprocess.getstatusoutput in Python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

When I tried the example`subprocess.getstatusoutput('ls /bin/ls')`, the result is "`(1, "'{'` is not recognized as an internal or external command,\noperable program or batch file.")", and every time I use `subprocess.getstatusoutput`, I got the same result, so could any one tell me what is the problem here and how could I fix it?

Comment: what are your OS, shell, python version?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce it on Ubuntu, this works:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

print(subprocess.getstatusoutput("ls /bin/ls"))

# is similar to 
print(subprocess.check_output("{ ls /bin/ls ; } 2>&1", shell=True))

# you could try this
print(subprocess.check_output(["ls", "/bin/ls"]))
```

#### Output

```py
(0, '/bin/ls')
b'/bin/ls\n'
b'/bin/ls\n'
```

See [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

The documentation for [`subprocess.getstatusoutput()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getstatusoutput) says that it is available only on Unix therefore it probably won't work on Windows.

Comment: my python information is: Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:29:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32.   Thanks J.F =)

Comment: Okay, that is the reason. Thanks a lot J.F, appreciate your help! =)